# Implementing live search using JavaScript and Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I am trying to make a livesearch feature similar to when you conduct a google search. The search queries cafes in my database by name.

I have gotten the functionality to the point where if the whole search value matches a cafe's name in the database it shows up for the user but would like to make it so the search value is checked as the user types, with cafes appearing until the user finishes typing (at which point there should only be one cafe remaining).

Here is what I have:

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function() {
  search()  
});
  

function search(){
  let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/electra/search/',
        data: {
          'search_term':searchTerm
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(searchTerm); //refer to below function for the running of this loop
            $("#search-results").text(data);
          }
        });
  };
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    template_name = 'testingland/write_image.html'
    search_term = request.GET.get('search_term', None)
    print(search_term)
    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(cafe_name = search_term)
    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```

I have been playing around with the `qs` filter but can't figure out the best way to approach this.

Comment: What do you  mean by "letter by letter"? That doesn't sound like it would give any useful search results. Do you want `mapCafes` instances where `cafe_name` contains `search_term`?

Comment: As the user types I want cafes to appear until the user finishes typing and there should only be one cafe remaining. I will update my OP to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```py
qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(cafe_name = search_term)
```

Here since you don't specify any lookup it is assumed to be an `exact` lookup, i.e. `cafe_name` must exactly match the `search_term` provided. Instead you want to be using some lookup like [`contains` [Django-docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or `icontains` so that you get all `mapCafes` instances that contain the given `search_term`:

```py
qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(cafe_name__icontains = search_term)
```

> **Note**: Class names in python should be in `PascalCase` by convention. Also model names should be **singular** so it should be
> `MapCafe` instead of <s>`mapCafes`</s>.

Comment: Awesome, works! And a great explanation. I have learned something new here, really appreciate it.